# divs cut in and out of visibility in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

Here's the page in question:

http://matt.jhousemedia3.com/pcrf/membership

I've only been able to recreate this result in Chrome on Windows (works in all other major browsers on windows and all browsers period on mac and linux).  When scrolling down the page the Recent News and Events section suddenly appears on the page when it should be displaying properly long before the user scrolls past it.  I thought this was a javascript error, but dont see any errors, and then I thought it was a weird rendering error, but cant find any documentation on an issue similar to this.  Any help would be appreciated.

[Here's a video](http://youtu.be/5PQ0uq5aVHY) showing what I'm talking about.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I think that if you want a good response here you should probably try to isolate the issue and make a jsfiddle. You seem to be having some resizing issues with the images in the childprogram-div. If you uncheck position:relative for div.childprogram in the Chrome Developers tools the problem disappears.